# Can any noun ending in -ism be swapped for -ist?

Tags: suffixes

Can any noun ending in -ism describing some system or belief be changed for -ist to describe a member of that system?

My question might be confusing, so I will run through a few examples:

```
Nihilism => nihilist
Feminism => feminist
Racism => racist
```

This seems to follow a pretty predictable pattern. So, when I learned a new word a while ago - *misoneism* (having a fear or hatred of innovation or change) - I was expecting to be able to call someone a *misoneist*, if it ever came to that.

Unfortunately, while most dictionaries (online and paper) I have checked so far contain the word *misoneism* they do not contain the word *misoneist*. Were my assumptions correct that you can create any -ist noun from a root of -ism, or is this word in the dictionary because it really doesn't exist?

Comment: The compulsive looking up in dictionaries, *dictionaryism*, is **only** practiced by *dictionaryists*. (Welcome to the club.)

Comment: Some Greek-derived terms have an -ism, but not (usually) an -ist, including _cynicism_ and _stoicism_.

Comment: [The Phrontistery](http://phrontistery.info/isms.html) has a list of 234 -isms. You could do individual searches for the use of the corresponding -ists. 'Illusionist' might cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It does seem that your proposition is by and large correct. One can think of a variety of exceptions, but it generally seems to hold that where you find an *...ism*, there will usually be an *...ist*!**

But not all followers of something are *...ists*, some are *...ites* e.g Luddites (I've never heard *Luddism* used, though).

Adherents of Nazism are plain *Nazis*. That is a clear exception of an *...ism*, without an *...ist*. I have no doubt that there are others and people will think of them.

In British politics you have had, at different times Benthamites, Brownites, Blairites, Bennites etc. But I am not sure if any were ...isms.

Of course it doesn't work the other way round. There are many *...ists* who do not follow an *...ism* e.g. *economist*, *sociologist* etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input WS2. It seems the -ite suffix is for when the follower was originally of a person or some other proper noun, such as Luddite after Ned Lud, Blairites after Tony Blair etc. It seems that most of the counter examples I can think of are where the root of the word existed first, and a new version of -ism or -ist came later.

Answer (score 2):

No - counter example:

> Catholicism => Catholic

but not

> Catholicist

Comment: Another counterexample: jism -/-> jist